# Stability of ortho and para hydrogen

Tags: hydrogen, spin

I have two books on inorganic chemistry, one says that ortho hydrogen is more stable while other says para is more stable. Even on Internet, there are websites some supporting the former fact and some the latter. So, which one is more stable?
I think that para hydrogen is more stable because opposite spins cancel each other's magnetic effect, hence leading to lower energy (it's purely a guess, I'm not at all familiar with spin or magnetism) and if my answer is incorrect then what explains the stability of correct spin isomer?

Comment: What do you know about nuclear spin statistics? How do they affect the symmetry of the other components of the nuclear wavefunction, most notably rotational?

Comment: @orthocresol Nothing. I have not even heard about nuclear spin statistics and so looking for a bit simplified explanation.

Comment: @DavePhD I have already read that question but that was a little off the scope, is there any simpler answer? Or explanation of the same thing but in a more intuitive way?

Comment: A bit meh on the duplicate. That answer doesn't answer this. @user375072 I don't think there is an intuitive way. The explanation is not about the relative orientation of the nuclear spin and whether they attract/repel each other. It is about the symmetry of the wavefunction upon exchange of identical particles (the two H nuclei) which is constrained by the spin statistics theorem (fermions, like H nuclei, have to have an antisymmetric wavefunction). para-H2 has a lowest rotational state of J = 0 and ortho-H2 has J = 1, which has a higher energy.

Comment: @user375072 the oversimplified explanation is that orthohydrogen cannot exist without rotating, while parahydrogen can; therefore, parahydrogen is lower energy (because ortho must have the energy of rotation).

Comment: @DavePhD Thank you very much, this explanation is enough to explain me the answer, thanks again:)